# How to implement Do nothing for a certain period of time in Android

Tags: android

Now I want to fire a specific event if there is no separate input for a certain amount of time in any TextView . Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer). it allows you to call a method on a specific interval.And your app will be responsive if you use this in the meantime.
Or you can use `Thread.sleep()` if you wish to do nothing for a certain period of time.

For your task, You can start a `Timer` once the TextView is initiated and check its value once the timer is done.

```
     int delay = 5000;// in ms 

      Timer timer = new Timer();

      timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
         public void run() { 
             //check the TextView value
          }
       }, delay);
```

Comment: Your answer is very intuitive and lightweight good code.
In my case, after comparing with Text after a few seconds through Handler in TextView, I assumed that if it was the same, there was no action.
I've already solved this problem, but this answer seems to be correct in most situations.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for taking your time. Perhaps a need for this implementation will come to me soon.